# Execute anonymous function within a funtion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, anonymous-function

Below is a javascript programme which i wrote :-

```
 ti();

function ti()
{      
   () =>
    {
       console.log("annonymous");      
    }  
   

 console.log("Hi ") ;

 
}
```

I am not able to figure out what is the mistake which is preventing  anonymous function getting executed. Can anyone please let me know what error I am making ?

Thank You

Comment: You aren’t calling it

Comment: You have declared it, but not executed it. try something like this `( ()=> {} )()`

Comment: @NickSlash , is it necessary that I put last set of bracket i.e ```()``` immediately after defining entire function ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it is exactly the same as your original code. Those brackets are what execute the code. Read the IIFE link in the answer from @blaccod for information

Comment: Thank you very much , actually I am learning new so facing lot of difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the function but didn't call it. You can read more about it here: [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
ti();

function ti()
{      
   (() =>
    {
    console.log("annonymous");      
    })()  
   

  console.log("Hi ") ;

 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me sir. I am actually learning Javascript recently so facing a lot of doubts. Thank you for clearing it.